# Using ASP.NET MVC as reverse proxy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We're looking for any kind of 'reverse proxy' logic in ASP.NET.

We have a controller receiving a request that has been authenticated by ASP.NET itself and then we'd like to 'forward' this request to a different internal machine in a trusted domain (keeping all the headers/params/cookies/...).

It is a way to hide the internal machine.

Any idea / solution is welcome.

Comment: I would suggest you use an ACTUAL reverse proxy, and not try and make a web server do the job.  Your actual reverse proxy can use the same authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using full IIS? If so then you can use the URL Rewrite and ARR modules. See http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: The request is authenticated by the ASP.NET code. How to secure the request to forward and pass the authenticated user name?